# Force redraw of svg when using <use> for svg data

Tags: javascript, ajax, svg, redraw

I have an svg element (#svg_wrapper) that displays using a  element which loads the svg data (updated by ajax) that are stored in the dom under a display:none div parent (#svg_loader). How can i force a redraw of the the svg data the  element uses after I load updated svg markup in the hidden div?

The usage of  is imperative in my case because that's the only way i can scale the loaded svg to my container's size (#timeline_wrapper).

I managed to successfully add the updated svg node in the #svg_loader , but then the browser doesn't re-render the changes. How can I force it to redraw the changed svg that just loaded in the DOM (and replaced the previous one) ?

```
<div id='svg_loader' style='display:none;'>
<svg id='svg_timeline'> ajax-updated svg data</svg>
</div>
<div id='timeline_wrapper' style='width:725px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:center;'>
<svg id='svg_wrapper' style='width:725px;height:352px;' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:x='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' >
<defs id='defs3006'>
<marker orient='auto' refY='0.0' refX='-3' id='Arrow2Mend' style='overflow:visible;'>
  <path id='path3900' style='fill-rule:evenodd;stroke-width:0.62500000;stroke-linejoin:round;' d='M -15 -5 L 0 0 L -15 5 z' transform='scale(0.5)'/>
</marker>
</defs>
<use xlink:href='#svg_timeline' x='0' y='-35' width='100%' height='100%' />
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about *flushing* the `innerHTML` of your hidden div and *reattaching* the new data?

As simple as:

```
var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById('yourHiddenDiv');
hiddenDiv.innerHTML = ''; 
hiddenDiv.innerHTML = svgData; //where svgData is your new svg string
```

**As a side note:**

Although changing the inner data of an SVG *should* force it to redraw, you could also try not to change the data of the SVG directly.

You can just substitute the whole SVG string with the new one - if you are not getting the whole SVG string data with the `<svg>` tags through your AJAX call, you could simply create your own string (in full SVG format) and just *concatenate* your AJAX data within it, then attach it through `innerHTML=yourFullSvgString` as explained above

Comment: I did that with $(hiddenDiv).html('whole <svg> data'); and no rerendering occurs. Is this because of the <use> in the displaying div?